# Python Pelican double backslashes in Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pelican

So I'm trying to generate a pelican based website. Html's been generated fine, but now pelican thinks that the path to these html pages are like:

```
j:\\DROPBOX\\PyCharmProjects\\site\\output\\my-page.html
```

which results in an error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'j:\\DROPBOX\\PyCharmProjects\\site\\output\\my-page.html'
```

looking forward to knowhow to get rid of these `\\`

Thanks!

Comment: How are you passing your path? You need to add some code

Comment: there's nowhere to pass a path, that is the problem. Pelican itself generates theses html files and then doesn't know how to find em

Comment: Can you edit the path before the search?